# Client Server Sensor data collection and ROS in C++

Tags: c++, server, client, infinite-loop, ros

Basically, I have different sensors and each sensor data is available at different ports (as a server)
Two things I need to do:

1. Write a client to connect to the server to get the data
2. Publish data to ROS
   (I prefer writing my program in C++)

I am trying to searching information on the internet but still have several doubts.

1. Can one client connect to many different servers? I mean creating many sockets in one main function?
2. Does client/server and ROS publish/subscribe have to be the main function? or can I write them in normal functions and call these functions in the main function?

I can write the main function which able to get data from the server and publish it to ROS. But it means for each sensor I need to write a main function. Then I need to run many programs. It is certainly not a good solution. Also, each ROS publisher has a while loop, many loops in one main function may be a problem.

If anyone has experience with this please give me some hint on how I can build my program correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know threads?

Comment: I guess what you will have to do is to write a **translator node which maps the sensor data to topics**. For this purpose you will likely have to use another library such as Boost ASIO to connect to the sensors. Then you register corresponding publishers which are responsible for publishing the data to ROS. In a main loop you then contact the sensors, get the sensor data and publish it as a ROS topic. I personally would actually the design the code (potentially with C++ templates) with input parameters so that actually **one translator node is responsible for remapping a single sensor only**.

Comment: @S.M. Yes, the thread is an option.

Comment: @2b-t Do you know any example which I can refer to?

Comment: @Thinsheep There are several tutorials on Boost ASIO available such as [this one for TCP](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264257/Socket-Programming-in-Cplusplus-using-boost-asio-T). I am sadly not aware of any though that combine Boost with ROS. You would probably write a class which encapsulates such a Boost ASIO connection as well as a ROS publisher. This class should hold a member function `publish` which connects to the (tcp?) server and gets the sensor data and then publishes onto the ROS publisher.

Comment: This member function is called inside an infinite loop of the main program in combination with `ros::spinOnce()`. Give it a try, write some code and update this post with your code then.

Comment: Just write one class for a single server port and topic, then we can have a look at the code and see how you could re-arrange it so it extends to multiple topics by making a (polymorphic) vector of these classes. Encapsulating it into a class will help you not to write a main function for each one of them.